# How to create multisignature transaction?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, multisignature

I have to create a multisignature transaction which the transaction should get signed with at least 2 private keys. Could anyone explain how to do it? I am using web3.py

```
import rlp

    from ethereum.transactions import Transaction
    tx = Transaction(
        nonce=web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.coinbase),
        gasprice=web3.eth.gasPrice,
        startgas=100000,
        to='0xd3cda913deb6f67967b99d67acdfa1712c293601',
        value=12345,
        data=b'',
    )
    tx.sign(the_private_key_for_the_from_account)
    raw_tx = rlp.encode(tx)
    raw_tx_hex = web3.toHex(raw_tx)
    web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(raw_tx_hex)
```

In the above code, I am only signing with one private key. Could anyone explain how to sign with multiple private keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Ethereum transaction should have only one signature, representing the account that will pay the gas for it. If you want to control a resource with multiple signatures, you have two options:

- Make a contract that requires multiple transactions to make whatever it is happen. See [this contract](https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/MultiSigWalletWithDailyLimit.sol) for an example.
- Instead of checking the transaction signature (in practice, `msg.sender`) like you would with a simple transaction, sign the *data* to the transaction and have your contract check it using `ecrecover`. This allows you to collect the signatures out-of-band and submit all the signature data in a single transaction. See [this contract](https://medium.com/@ChrisLundkvist/exploring-simpler-ethereum-multisig-contracts-b71020c19037) for an example.